# Eclipse shows splash screen and closes. How to fix?

Tags: eclipse

Today I restarted my machine, and Eclipse (3.5, downloaded recently) shows a strange behaviour:

- shows splash screen for less than a sec
- quits

This is in 100% of the cases, so I can't start Eclipse at all.

Where can I find logs about this?

I deleted all eclipse resources and re-unzipped it. Same thing.

I have enough memory (IntelliJ runs fine), and my anti-virus software doesn't show any activity related to closing eclipse.

Any ideas what might have caused this?

Comment: As other tools closely related to coding activities, I have always considered eclipse (like Git, SVN, ...) as a SO topic, certainly not a SU ("General computer software or hardware troubleshooting") topic. That being said, if you have your answer, that is all that matter.

Comment: I reinstall JDK and JRE and my eclipse runs again :D

Answer (score 44):

one thing that i've come up with is deleting the folder:

```
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench"
```

where `workspace` is your eclipse workspace directory

Comment: Super!! +1 for the solution.Saved me a lot of headache.

Comment: @GuruM I wonder how I got this solution. maybe I did a binary search about which folder to remove, once I've found out that deleting all of them also fixes it.

Comment: I cant seem to find that

Comment: can someone please share the full path of the folder? thank you.

Comment: @Rodniko That's when the projects you create are created. You can check it in the settings screen too.

Comment: Awesome, saved the day! The issue was I was using viewing a _gigantic_ file (loading to an embedded H2 db, not a class file ;), and the log showed eclipse was running out of memory at startup, probably because it was trying to load that crazy file, so deleting the current 'workbench' did the trick. Apparently after all these years, the built in editor or memory management within eclipse is still lacking. Can't complain too much - it is free software - but to get stuck in a state like this where you almost have to reinstall the workspace seems to be a bit much..

Comment: This is the best solution for the whoops I clicked on a big file and now eclipse will not open any more scenario.

Answer (score 9):

Start it from the command-line and see if it produces any error messages.

Comment: how exactly?...

Comment: On windows, it is best to use the console version of the executable when running from the command line, so something like "eclipsec -consoleLog -debug" might be useful.

Comment: getting error in console: `Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object`

Comment: if I do add [`-vm <path-to-javaw.exe>`](http://superuser.com/questions/148179/eclipse-shows-splash-screen-and-closes-how-to-fix/148183#148183) then getting error `could not create virtual machine`

Answer (score 5):

I added this in eclipse.ini:

```
-vm 
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_20/jre/bin/javaw.exe
```

And it started. Then, however, one of my projects (a simple test project) did not resolve `java.lang.String` and `java.lang.System`. I changed the JRE to JDK/JRE, and it worked.

`JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` were pointing to the above location.

Comment: The eclipse launcher does not consult JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME.  It looks on the system search path.  This might be useful: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher

Comment: +1 If the Java installation on the system is messed up, or if the system default Java VM does not work with Eclipse, this lets you explicitly tell Eclipse which VM to use.

Answer (score 4):

There's a `.log` file in the `.metadata` directory inside each workspace, which often contains a number of stack traces from the Eclipse internals. Startup crashes are usually found here. I'm assuming you have Eclipse configured to start up in a specific workspace automatically, without prompting you to pick one at startup.

Comment: yes, but it was empty. It didn't get to the workspace resolution at all.

Comment: There can also be a <timestamp>.log file in the eclipse/configuration folder if we didn't get far enough to have a workspace.

Comment: What if you're not using eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

I have found that starting eclipse up with the arguments `-clean -clearPersistedState` will often fix crashes for me.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: Try starting Eclipse with -clean (which re-scans the installed plugins and rebuilds the caches in $ECLIPSE_HOME/configuration).

Generally, you get back your projects after removing .metadata with import->existing projects.

Alteratively, some project's .settings may be damaged.

Look at the error stack (in .metadata/.log) to find out which plugin is making problems, and try to remove its prefs.

An easy way to try all this is to create a new workspace (start eclipse with -data if you don't get the dialog) and to manually copy the projects over.

Answer (score 1):

Open eclipse.ini.  If the line `-showsplash` is there, remove it.

If it is not present, add `-nosplash`

I know it's strange recommending to not show the splash screen, but it occasionally causes issues on some machines / Java configurations.

Comment: Crazy as it sounds, this was the only thing that worked for me when updating to Eclipse 23.0.2.1259578

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and nothing worked for me using Eclipse Luna 64 bit.  I had originally had Java 1.6, Java 1.7 and Java 1.8 installed, but had removed Java 1.8 using the Windows 7 control panel.  I saw the splash screen once for a split second, then that was it and no errors, no log files, nor a .lock file.

I had been working through a different error (error code 13) with 32 bit/ 64 bit incompatibilities between java and eclipse.  So I settled on 64 bit for both to get around that issue.  Then afterwards I reinstalled Java 1.8 back in again it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to tweak anything in eclipse.ini, ensure you keep a copy of the original. For me it was as simple as -Xmx was set to 5 instead of 5g